# Is there "UPDATE value IF NO SUCH ROW INSERT yyy" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update a table value on Mysql 5 but if the key does not exist create it.

The way I found to do it is by:

```
INSERT yyy ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field;
```

The question is : is the format above less efficient than other ways to do it (As the insert will happen only once and update will happen very often)?

for example:

```
$result = UPDATE field; 
if (num_rows_effected($result)==0) INSERT yyy
```

Furthermore: Is there a better way to do this in Mysql: for example a kind of:

```
UPDATE value IF NO SUCH ROW INSERT yyy;
```

Update: For those who suggested REPLACE, here is an extension to my question:
"Thanks! I need to increase a counter that is already in the table (if it exists). If not create a table row with value 1 for this column. How can I do update with this format (REPLACE)? "

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) also.

`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will fire `UPDATE` triggers when it will stumble upon a duplicate key and won't violate `FK`'s in case on `UPDATE`.

`REPLACE` will fire `DELETE` and `INSERT` triggers, and will violate `FK`'s referencing the row being `REPLACE`'d.

If you don't have any triggers or `FK`'s, then use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it's most efficient.

You seem to be looking for this query:

```
INSERT
INTO table (key, counter)
VALUES (@key, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  counter = counter + 1
```

You cannot do this with `REPLACE` unless you have selected previous value of the counter before running the query.

*P. S.* `REPLACE` appeared in `MySQL` before `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and is being kept only for compatibility. There is no performance increase from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the 'replace' syntax:

```
REPLACE INTO table1 (key, col1, col2) values (1, 'val1','val2');
```

This is a feature specific to MySQL and is not necessarily implemented in other databases.

As for efficiency, my guess is that a straight update will be faster, since MySQL essentially catches the duplicate key error and handles it accordingly.  However, unless you are doing large amounts of insert/updates, the performance impact will be fairly small.

Comment: Thanks!
I need to increase a counter that is already in the table (if it exists). If not create a table row with value 1 for this column. How can I do update with this format?

Comment: This deletes the old row, and creates a new one, and has many other issues, so don't use this unless you are happy to have something similar to `DELETE FROM ...; INSERT INTO ...`

Answer (score -1):

Look at the REPLACE command, it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks!
I need to increase a counter that is already in the table (if it exists). If not create a table row with value 1 for this column. How can I do update with this format?